# Content cropped instead of wrapping

Tags: css, text, width

This might be a dumb question, but in [this page (link)](http://jiiiiii.com/office-name-generator.html) why doesn't h2 element wrap as h1 does , meaning when browser zoomed the text in h2 goes outside while h1 wraps to the next line. What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to look at those two strings. The h1 one has an 'ordinary' space between the words, the h2 one has a non-breakng space instead. As it says, the system isn't allowed to break on that sort of space.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect it in h2 the generator adds `&nbsp;` like white space, so it is only one word.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Yep now  I see why. lol. Thanks